# Payment Card Industry DSS - Storing card holder data in systems not connected to internet

Tags: pci-dss

## Background

Though I've looked through some posts on stack-overflow that partially cover this point I'm yet to find one that provides a comprehensive question/answer.

As a developer of POS systems the PCI DSS has two components I'm interested in:

- PA DSS (Payment Application) which regards the software I develop
- PCI DSS (Merchants) which regards all my clients that use the software

The PA DSS seems to put the point most bluntly:

"9.1 The payment application must be developed such that the database server and web server are not required to be on the same server, nor is the database server required to be in the DMZ with the web server"

Testing Procedures:

9.1.a To verify that the payment application stores cardholder data in the internal network, and never in the DMZ, obtain evidence that the payment application does not require data storage in the DMZ, and will allow use of a DMZ to separate the Internet from systems storing cardholder data (e.g., payment application must not require that the database server and web server be on the same server, or in the DMZ with the web server).

9.1.b If customers could store cardholder data on a server connected to the Internet, examine PA-DSS Implementation Guide prepared by vendor to verify customers and resellers/integrators are told not to store cardholder data on Internet-accessible systems (e.g., web server and database server must not be on same server).

And from the merchant's PCI DSS:

1.3.5 Restrict outbound traffic from the cardholder data environment to the Internet such that outbound traffic can only access IP addresses within the DMZ.

### Question

My question is quite simple - can the database and application server be logically different (on different virtualised OS) or must they be physically different (on different physical/dedicated servers)?

Also, I'm a bit concerned about having to place a database server with no connection to the Internet whatsoever. How am I supposed to administer this server remotely? 
Or is it okay to access the database server via the application server - though surely that defeats the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

No simple answer, sadly.

The SSC has released a new supplement on virtualisation which has some relevant information: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Virtualization_InfoSupp_v2.pdf

While mixing guest OSs of different functions on the same hypervisor is not prohibited, you will need to show that you've thought about the extra risk that this brings.

They will also have to be logically separated with network traffic from one VM to the other going through a firewall of some sort to protect the different OSs and applications. Being on the same physical host is not an excuse for skipping controls like firewalling so you may have to be creative about how you meet these requirements.